# Angular SPA page doesn't display all the time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

Hello evryone am having a weird problem. I have an Angular spa. But one page doesn't get displayed all the time. It works at first then it doesnt work. I dont understand

Here is my angular code :

```
//chirpApp.js
var app = angular.module('chirpApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).run(function($rootScope, $http) {
  $rootScope.authenticated = false;
  $rootScope.current_user = '';

  $rootScope.signout = function(){
      $http.get('auth/signout');
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      $rootScope.current_user = '';
  };
});

app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    //the timeline display
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'mainController'
    })
    //the login display
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller: 'authController'
    })
    //the signup display
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'register.html',
      controller: 'authController'
    });
});

app.factory('postService', function($resource){
  return $resource('/api/posts/:id');
});

app.controller('mainController', function(postService, $scope, $rootScope){
  $scope.posts = postService.query();
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

  $scope.post = function() {
    $scope.newPost.created_by = $rootScope.current_user;
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    postService.save($scope.newPost, function(){
      $scope.posts = postService.query();
      $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
    });
  };
});

app.controller('authController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location){
  $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};
  $scope.error_message = '';

  $scope.login = function(){
    $http.post('/auth/login', $scope.user).success(function(data){
      if(data.state == 'success'){
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
        $location.path('/');
      }
      else{
        $scope.error_message = data.message;
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.register = function(){
    $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data){
      if(data.state == 'success'){
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
        $location.path('/');
      }
      else{
        $scope.error_message = data.message;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

And here is my main html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chirp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/chirpApp.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="chirpApp">
    <div id='main' class="container">
      <nav class="navbar-fluid navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Chirp! </a>
          <p class="navbar-text"> Learn the MEAN stack by building this tiny app</p>
          <p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-hide="authenticated"><a href="#/login">Login</a> or <a href="#/signup">Register</a></p>
          <p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-show="authenticated"><a href="#" ng-click="signout()">Logout</a></p>
          <p class="navbar-right navbar-text" ng-show="authenticated">Signed in as {{current_user}}</p>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my partial :

```
  <form class="form-auth" ng-submit="register()">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <p class="text-warning">{{error_message}}</p>
    <input type="username" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </form>
```

Please help

Comment: If you are using a browser that supports debugging (e.g. Chrome), open the debugging window (F12 in Chrome) and check what is written in the console tab (if anything is written at all). Unfortunately, when you have errors they are not normally shown on screen unless you add some error handling.

Comment: hey 10q for your reply but nothing is written on the console